# Solve $f'=\sqrt{|1-f|}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all continuously differentiable $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such
> that $f'(x)=\sqrt{|1-f(x)|}$.

I am a little thrown off by the absolute value inside the square root. I can solve $f'=\sqrt{1-f}$ or $f'=\sqrt{f-1}$ easily enough by separating variables, getting that $f$ is a certain quadratic function of $x$. However, I'm not sure what to do with the integral with the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$f(x)=1$ is solution at $\Bbb R$.

Let us look for an other solution satisfying
$$(\exists a\in \Bbb R)\;:\; f(a)>1$$
$f $ is continuous at $ a $, so there exists an intervall $ J $ where $ f(x)>1$.

in this case, the equation becomes
$$\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)-1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
which gives by integration
$$\sqrt{f(x)-1}=\frac{x}{2}+C$$
and
$$f(x)=1+(\frac x2+C)^2$$

do the same in the case $ f(a)<1$.

Comment: How can you patch together these different (local) solutions then? I guess the continuously differentiable condition comes into play?

Comment: For $ C=0 $, you have a solution at $[0,+\infty)$ continuously differentiable.